# Store output from my bash script in a .txt file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I want store the output of my script in a file, but can't.

This is:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
echo "Te falta especificar una dirección ip"
echo "Syntax esperado: ./hostDiscovery.sh <ip>"

else
for ip in `seq 1 254`; do
ping -c 1 $1.$ip | grep "64 bytes" | cut -d " " -f 4 | tr -d ":" | tee ip.txt &
done
fi
```

The problem is that the file that was created has no data. It is blank.

Comment: This script is part of a course that I'm doing about bash scripting, and it is a variant of Nmap that not so much efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quickly answer your question, simply replace your last pipe `... -d ":" | tee ip.txt &` with `... -d ":" >> ip.txt &`

- The `>>` syntax will append to *ip.txt*. You can also use `tee -a` to append but that will also print to stdout.
- If you want to make sure that file is cleared each time you run the script you will want to: `> ip.txt` at the top of your script to clear *ip.txt*.

Here is what your new script might look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
    echo "Te falta especificar una dirección ip"
    echo "Syntax esperado: ./hostDiscovery.sh <ip>"
else
    > ip.txt
    for ip in `seq 1 254`; do
        ping -c 1 $1.$ip | grep "64 bytes" | cut -d " " -f 4 | tr -d ":" | tee -a ip.txt &
    done
fi
```

I have a lot to say about this script though. It looks like you are trying to ping all ip addresses within a range to test to see if they are up/alive. You may want to look into [nmap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap)

e.g. `nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-254`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I had also tried use >>, but I get into an "error". The file that remains, it saves the information, but if I use the script again the new information is added to the file, which I don't want. I want that the file is overwritten every time I use the script.

Comment: Very good comment, I can see why you might want that. To clear the contents of a file simply do `> filename.txt` at the top of you script. I will change my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting ip.txt on each call to tee.

Try calling tee -a to append.

man tee for details

Comment: Also thanks for the response. Same from above "If I use the script again the new information is added to the file, which I don't want. I want that the file is overwritten every time I use the script."

Comment: You still want tee -a, just truncate the file at the beginning of your script. echo "" > ip.txt before the loop starts would get you the end result I think you want.

Comment: I will add, while I think tee -a is the best answer to your question as asked, it would probably be better practice to pull file writing out of your script altogether, and instead just call it like ./myscript.sh > ip.txt or ./myscript.sh | tee ip.txt to get the result you want.